# Google Cloud Dataflow can't import 'google.cloud.datastore'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

This is my import code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import datetime
import json
import logging
import re

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import combiners
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from apache_beam.pvalue import AsDict
from apache_beam.pvalue import AsSingleton
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from google.cloud import datastore
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper, PropertyFilter

# datastore entities that we need to perform the mapping computations
#from models import UserPlan, UploadIntervalCount, RollingMonthlyCount
```

This is what my requirements.txt file looks like

```
$ cat requirements.txt
Flask==0.12.2
apache-beam[gcp]==2.1.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
google-cloud-dataflow==2.1.1
six==1.10.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
google-cloud
```

This is all in the `/lib` directory. The `/lib` directory has the following

```
$ ls -1 lib/google/cloud
__init__.py
_helpers.py
_helpers.pyc
_http.py
_http.pyc
_testing.py
_testing.pyc
bigquery
bigtable
client.py
client.pyc
datastore
dns
environment_vars.py
environment_vars.pyc
error_reporting
exceptions.py
exceptions.pyc
gapic
iam.py
iam.pyc
language
language_v1
language_v1beta2
logging
monitoring
obselete.py
obselete.pyc
operation.py
operation.pyc
proto
pubsub
resource_manager
runtimeconfig
spanner
speech
speech_v1
storage
translate.py
translate.pyc
translate_v2
videointelligence.py
videointelligence.pyc
videointelligence_v1beta1
vision
vision_v1
```

Notice that both `google.cloud.datastore` and `google.cloud.proto` exist in the `/lib` folder. However, this import line works fine

`from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2`

but this one failed

`from google.cloud import datastore`

This is the exception (taken from the google cloud dataflow console online)

```
(9b49615f4d91c1fb): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 166, in execute
    op.start()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 294, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10607)
    def start(self):
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 295, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:10501)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 300, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start (apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.c:9702)
    pickler.loads(self.spec.serialized_fn))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 225, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 767, in _import_module
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_pipeline/counters_pipeline.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.cloud import datastore
ImportError: No module named datastore
```

Why can't it find the package?

Comment: External dependencies must be installed in `setup.py` and this file should be specified in pipeline parameters.

Comment: is google.cloud an external dependency? What makes it different from the google.cloud.proto.v1.datastore dependency that's installed in the /lib directory that I have no trouble accessing? Anyway, I'll give it a try. I just need to add `google-cloud` to the `REQUIRED_PACKAGES` list inside of setup.py?

Comment: Hey @MarcinZablocki,  your answer was correct, thank you very much! I'm still confused though why some stuff can go in the /lib directory and be linked in the appengine_config.py file but other stuff has to be in the setup.py file. Maybe you could expand on that and write it as a full blown answer?

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki Just saw it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External dependencies must be installed in `setup.py` and this file should be specified in pipeline parameters as `--setup_file`. 
In the `setup.py` you can either install you package by using **custom command**

```
pip install google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0
```

or by adding you package into `REQUIRED_PACKAGES`:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ["google-cloud-datastore==1.3.0"]
```

The reason why you need to specify it in `setup.py` is because libraries you have in `appengine_config` are not used during the DataFlow execution. App Engine only acts as a scheduler here, which only deploys job to DataFlow engine. Then, DataFlow creates some worker machines which execute your pipeline - those workers are not connected by any means to the App Engine. DataFlow workers must have every package required for your pipeline to execute, that's why you need to specify required packages in the `setup.py` file. DataFlow workers use this file to "setup themselves".